# Unity: error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration,

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax-error

I'm new to coding, and from what I gathered, the following code was written to be compatible with C# 4.0 not the current version. There is also another error that I couldn't fit in the title:
  Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class camera_controller : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject player;
    private Vector3 offset;
    Vector3 offset = transform.position;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void LateUpdate () 
    {

    transform.position=player.transform.position+offset;

    }

}
```

Comment: *I'm new to coding* then you should start by learning some C# basics ... I bet that you put this code directly inside class body not method body... but it's just a blind guess without [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a type for the variable.

transform.position is the type Vector3.

try this:

Vector3 offset = transform.position;

Comment: error CS0102: The type 'camera_controller' already contains a definition for 'offset'

Comment: 2 things: you can't have two variables in the same scope with the same name (offset and offset) and you need to put the line where you set the value inside a function

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `Vector3 offset = transform.position;` and add `offset = transform.position;` under `Start()` or `Awake()` and see below link for more info. C# does not allow field initializers besides constants, constructors and static fields. `transform.position` is a non-static field.

[Why can't I assign transform.position to a Vector3 object?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1219768/why-cant-i-assign-a-vector3-object-the-transformpo.html)